# iOS VPN ondemand shut off from settings app

Tags: ios, vpn, networkextension, nevpnmanager

Turning off the VPN from the settings app doesn't turn off the ondemand feature. Trying to access the NETunnelProviderManager and setting ondemand to false results in the log message NEVPNManager objects cannot be instantiated from NEProvider processes. But if a user manually shuts off the VPN from the settings app I want to provide the option for ondemand to be shut off as well.

Using an instance of var targetManager: NEVPNManager = NEVPNManager.sharedManager() inside of the extension does work if the UI is still alive in the background.

Does anyone know of a work around when the container app is dead?

Comment: Filed an enhancement feature with apple. Radar #27054775

Answer (score 0):

The user can switch on/off the onDemand from the settings, but not in a convenient way - he has to go to Settings->General->VPN and then he can choose the VPN settings and set the onDemand.

It would be a lot better if it can be done from the VPN switch at the Setting page, so let's hope Apple would accept your Radar.

Comment: Yes Im aware about the user being able to manually shut up off.. It is highly inconvenient. I'm not sure why we would not have access to that toggle inside the extension.. It is still an open case so thats good.